# I wanna get all multiple files in listview in c# like "ppt,docx,and txxt but i get only one at a time"

Tags: c#

It does work but not complete my need.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listView1.Items.Clear();
    if (textBox1.Text != "")
    {
        List<string> files = new List<string>();
        files = Directory.GetFiles(textBox1.Text, "*.txt,*.ppt").ToList();
        progressBar1.Maximum = files.Count;
        progressBar1.Value = 0;
        ListViewItem it;
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            it = new ListViewItem(file.ToString());
            it.SubItems.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.ToString()));
            it.SubItems.Add(System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file.ToString()));
            listView1.Items.Add(it);
            progressBar1.Increment(1);
        }
    }
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Select directory first");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GetFiles doesnt take multiple extensions

your : `files = Directory.GetFiles(textBox1.Text, "*.txt,*.ppt").ToList();`

would be come

```
String[] extensions= new String[] {"txt","ppt"};

foreach (String extension in extensions) 
  files.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(textBox1.Text, "*."+extension));
```

This would give you your results.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than calling `GetfFiles` multiple times you could also iterate over the files once and check for your extensions:

```
var extentions[] = {".txt", ".ppt"};
var all_files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\Directory");
foreach (string current_file in all_files)
{
    foreach (var ext in extensions)
    {
       if (current_file.EndsWith(ext) 
       {
          // do what you need
       }
    }
}
```

You could include code for stepping through sub-directories as well.