# Get files in directory with multiple search patterns

Tags: c#, io

I have a method that gets files in specified directory with extension `txt`. Besides those files, I want to also get files with extensions `ppt`, `docx` etc. How to achieve that?

this is my current code:

```cs
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
  listView1.Items.Clear();
  if (textBox1.Text != ""){
    List<string> files = new List<string>();
    files = Directory.GetFiles(textBox1.Text, "*.txt,*.ppt").ToList();
    progressBar1.Maximum = files.Count;
    progressBar1.Value = 0;
    ListViewItem it;
    foreach (var file in files){
      it = new ListViewItem(file.ToString());
      it.SubItems.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.ToString()));
      it.SubItems.Add(System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file.ToString()));
      listView1.Items.Add(it);
      progressBar1.Increment(1);
    }
  } else
    MessageBox.Show("Select directory first");
}
```

Comment: it works, but does not complete your need in what way?  Try to be more specific.  What are you getting?  How does it differ from what you expect/need?

Comment: Use Linq :             files = Directory.GetFiles("textBox1.Text", "*.*").Where(x => x.EndsWith(".txt") || x.EndsWith(".ppt")).ToList();

Comment: Why did you ask this question twice? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37113147/i-wanna-get-all-multiple-files-in-listview-in-c-sharp-like-ppt-docx-and-txxt-bu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not clear but which i understand you want to get files with different extension from a specified path. We can't do this using **Directory.GetFiles("c://etc.", "*.txt")** because it works on a single search pattern. You can use this,

```
string[] Extensions = {"*.txt", "*.doc", "*.ppt"};
foreach(var ext in Extensions)
{
    GetFiles(ext);
}
private void GetFiles(string ext)
{
    List<string> files = new List<string>();
    files = Directory.GetFiles("c:/something", ext).ToList();
    // Something you want to do with these files.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
files = Directory.GetFiles(@textBox1.Text, "*.txt").ToList();
files.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(@textBox1.Text, "*.docx").ToList());
files.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(@textBox1.Text, "*.ppt").ToList());
```

also, you should consider checking for validity of path from textBox1, something like this:

```
if (!Directory.Exists(@textBox1.Text))
{
   MessageBox.Show("invalid folder");
   return;
}
```

Comment: doesn't `AddRange` throw an exception if nothing is present in the collection to be added?  Might want to take that into account

Comment: nope, it won't throw exception. Directory.GetFiles will return empty List<string> collection which then will be 'added'. But the contents of `textBox1.Text` could :)